# Mozilla Push Service: 413 - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: push-notification, push, mozilla, web-push

I'm sending push notifications to Mozilla's Push Service:

```
https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/...
```

This is working really well for a long time now, but since two weeks I get an 413 - Request Entity Too Large for one (and only this one) of the consumers.

I searched the web for that error message, but all I found was the limit of 4KB for most of the push services. But the payload I am sending is much smaller:

```
{
    "Titel": "New calendar entry from subdomain.domain.com",
    "Text": "A new entry has been made by firstname lastname in the calendar your-calendar-name on 2021/02/03.",
    "Icon": "https:\/\/subdomain.domain.com\/version\/webapp\/icon192.png",
    "URL": "https:\/\/subdomain.domain.com\/calendar\/event\/15578"
}
```

So my question is: what can cause this Request Entity Too Large error when I'm sending a payload that's under 4KB?

Comment: No ideas on that? The error occurs again and again even tough I've shortened the payload...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across something very like this problem today. The cause of the problem was Firefox for Android, which behaves differently from Firefox for desktop.
URLs for the desktop version are like this: [https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/[something]](https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/%5Bsomething%5D)
The android version URLs are like this: [https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/[something]](https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/%5Bsomething%5D)

Note v2 as opposed to v1

The requests to the v1 endpoint were all returning with `413 Request Entity Too Large`

The difference is that the desktop version accepts the standard 4078 bytes, but the Android version seems to have a lower limit (possibly 3052 bytes).

I use minishlink's php library for sending push notifications, and I found some information about this here: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php#payload-length-security-and-performance

This document says that the default is compatible with Firefox for Android (3052 bytes), but in practice I could only get it to work when I added the line

`$webPush->setAutomaticPadding(false);`

to my code. So if you happen to be using a library that pads the payload for security reasons, that might be your problem.

For more discussion, see https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php/issues/108, which suggests that 2847 bytes, not 3052, is the actual limit in practice for payload to Firefox for Android.

Comment: I'm also using Minishlink's WebPush library so thank you very much for your hint. I've now also set the automatic padding to false and then let's see if it works.

Comment: Until now this error has not occurred again. So I think this does the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: WARNING: This is fine if you're using push notifications for marketing purposes. But if you're sending secure information to the client (such as a 2-factor authentication key), please use ```$webPush->setAutomaticPadding($MY_PADDING_LIMIT);```Make sure to set ```$MY_PADDING_LIMIT``` to something larger than the longest message you’ll be sending to the client to prevent an attacker from guessing the content based on the length. Longer messages mean better encryption. But if you raise the limit too high, you run the risk of clients running under-resourced browsers not receiving your messages.